# Comparing objects in an Array extension causing error in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to build an extension that adds some of the convenience functionality of NSArray/NSMutableArray to the Swift Array class, and I'm trying to add this function:

```
func indexOfObject(object:AnyObject) -> Int? {

    if self.count > 0 {
        for (idx, objectToCompare) in enumerate(self) {
            if object == objectToCompare {
                return idx
            }
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

But unfortunately, this line:

```
if object == objectToCompare {
```

Is giving the error:

> could not find an overload for '==' that accepts the supplied arguments

#### Question

What am I doing wrong to cause this error?

#### Example

```
extension Array {

    func indexOfObject(object:AnyObject) -> Int? {

        if self.count > 0 {
            for (idx, objectToCompare) in enumerate(self) {
                if object == objectToCompare {
                    return idx
                }
            }
        }

        return nil
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to compare the objects themselves or just check if they point to the same object?

Comment: Is this an exercise? You should be able to use Cocoa/`NSArray`'s `indexOfObject:` on an `Array`.

Comment: @JoshCaswell -- Yes, how do they do it?

Comment: How do they do which?

Comment: @JoshCaswell -- The indexOfObject isn't available on Array type variables, only on NSArray type variables.  I'd like to add an extension that provides the functionality w/ native swift w/o the need to bridge to objective-c -- mostly just because I'm experimenting.

Comment: Fair enough; just wanted to be sure you knew of the possibility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always create an extension that uses NSArray's indexOfObject, e.g:

```
extension Array {
    func indexOfObject(object:AnyObject) -> Int? {
        return (self as NSArray).indexOfObject(object)
    }
}
```

You can specify that your array items can be compared with the `<T : Equatable>` constraint, then you can cast your object into `T` and compare them, e.g:

```
extension Array {
    func indexOfObject<T : Equatable>(o:T) -> Int? {
        if self.count > 0 {
            for (idx, objectToCompare) in enumerate(self) {
                let to = objectToCompare as T
                if o == to {
                    return idx
                }
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there much of a cost involved in the bridging?  I guess my thinking was that keeping it native would ultimately be better in the long run.

Comment: @Logan I imagine calling Obj-C code from Swift would be highly optimized

Comment: Any thoughts on how to compare objects like this in general?  I'd perhaps like to implement similar functionality in an extension.

Answer (score 7):

Actually there is no need to implement `indexOfObject:`; there is a global function `find(array, element)` already.

Comment: It came as a surprise to me too.

Comment: Any chance you could point me to where you found this? Possibly a place where others like it exist?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you have to do something like this:

```
func indexOfObject<T: Equatable>(object: T) -> Int? {
```

and so on.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is painfully obvious, but would you mind elaborating just a touch more.  I'm getting the same error with this.

Comment: We can't know that there exists a `==` operator for any two `AnyObjects`. The `<>` syntax specifies a generic. They're like templates in C++. The `Equatable` keyword basically means that a comparison operator for `T == T` exists.

Comment: I, too, get the same error, but the docs say that Equatable objects must define the == operator, yet it still doesn't seem to compile. I suspect it's because Swift is not yet ready for prime time.

Comment: Actually, if I'd spent two seconds reading mythz's answer, I would have seen why.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a relevant example from Apple's "The Swift Programming Language" in the "Generics" section:

```
func findIndex<T: Equatable>(array: T[], valueToFind: T) -> Int? {
    for (index, value) in enumerate(array) {
        if value == valueToFind {
            return index
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

The key idea here is that both `value` and `valueToFind` must of a type that is guaranteed to have the `==` operator implemented/overloaded. The `<T: Equatable>` is a generic that allows only objects of a type that are, well, equatable.

In your case, we would need to ensure that the array itself is composed only of objects that are equatable. The `Array` is declared as a struct with a generic `<T>` that does not require it to be equatable, however. I don't know whether it is possible to use extensions to change what kind of types an array can be composed of. I've tried some variations on the syntax and haven't found a way.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the compare part to another helper function, for example

```
extension Array {
    func indexOfObject(object: T, equal: (T, T) -> Bool) -> Int? {

        if self.count > 0 {
            for (idx, objectToCompare) in enumerate(self) {
                if equal(object, objectToCompare) {
                    return idx
                }
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3]

arr.indexOfObject(3, ==) // which returns {Some 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close. Here's a working extension:

```
extension Array {
    func indexOfObject<T: Equatable>(object:T) -> Int? {
        if self.count > 0 {
            for (idx, objectToCompare) in enumerate(self) {
                if object == objectToCompare as T {
                    return idx
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Swift had no way of knowing if *object* or *objectToCompare* were equatable. By adding generic information to the method, we're then in business.